# Error ImproperlyConfigured Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name, Django

Tags: python, django, web, djangorestframework

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Django-REST, en la que una empresa puede tener varios talleres, el problema es que cuando creo una empresa y luego intento entrar al ViewSet de los talleres, me sale el siguiente error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "enterprise-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?, solo pasa cuando hay empresas creadas, si no hay empresas me deja entrar entrar al ViewSet de los talleres, aquí el código:

Archivo `models.py`:

```
#modelo para empresas
class Enterprise(models.Model):
   nit = models.CharField(db_column='NIT', primary_key=True, max_length=12)  
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=8)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

   class Meta:
      db_table = 'enterprise'

#modelo para talleres
class Workship(models.Model):
   idworkship = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   description = models.TextField()
   type_service = models.CharField(db_column='type_Service', max_length=45)  
   stars = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
   field_bahias_quant = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='_bahias_quant')
   #clave foránea a Enterprise
   enterprise_nit = models.ForeignKey(Enterprise, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='enterprise_NIT') 

   def __str__(self):
    return self.name

   class Meta:
      db_table = 'workship'
      unique_together = (('idworkship', 'enterprise_nit'),)
```

Archivo `serializers.py`:

```
class EnterpriseSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = models.Enterprise
       fields = ('nit', 'name', 'type',)

class WorkshipSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = models.Workship
       fields = ('name','ubication', 'description', 'type_service', 'stars', 'votes', 'email' , 'field_bahias_quant', 'enterprise_nit',)
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class EnterpriseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.Enterprise.objects.all()
   serializer_class= serializers.EnterpriseSerializer

class WorkshipViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.Workship.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.WorkshipSerializer
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Enterprise', views.EnterpriseViewSet, base_name = 'Enterprise')
router.register('Workship', views.WorkshipViewSet, base_name = 'Workship')
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include(router.urls)),
   path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia lo siguiente en tu serializer:

```
...
class WorkshipSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    enterprise_nit = HyperlinkedRelatedField()
...
```

Las relaciones entre modelos se tienen que declarar explicitamente.
Ademas puede usar otro tipo de serializador para relaciones ademas de `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, por ejemplo `StringRelatedField` o `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Tambien tienes tu `related_name='enterprise_NIT'` con mayusculas. Cambialas a minusculas para que tengas los nombres definidos de forma regular.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dijo el usuario loki es cierto pero falta algo, el método HyperlinkedRelatedField recibe dos parámetros, un view name y el queryset, por lo que el serializer queda así:

```
...
class WorkshipSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
enterprise_nit = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='Enterprise-detail', queryset = models.Enterprise.objects.all())
...
```

Hago esta respuesta por si alguien mas llega a esta pregunta por tener el mismo problema.